# unwanted white box over the corner of a figure

Tags: floats, formatting

*** UPDATE ***

I tried a bunch of photos and found out that the issue only happens when the image is not in the shape of a square (i.e if the image is rectangular like my case)

I am also using a double column kind of layout for the paper

How do I solve this issue?

*** UPDATE ***

This is the portion of the code for the figure which I usually used for all figures. However, I have an issue with only one of the figures.

What I get is a white box covering the top right corner through the middle of the box.

I tried changing the place of the figure but with no luck.

I used texstudio, in the preview everything looks good, however when I access the saved PDF file I find that issue.

More details: the image is in PNG. It shouldn't be an issue because I never had this issue with other PNGs (and also with the same image in old compilation).

What could be the issue?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics [scale=0.5]{figurefilename}
    \caption{Figure Caption.}
    \label{fig:label}
 \end{figure}
```

This is only a portion of the image, I did not screenshot the whole image, just the problematic region.

[image]

Comment: With this fragment of code and don't having the relevant `.png` file at hand there is not much to say about this.

Comment: that's distinctly odd, are you sure the image looks OK if you look at it in an image viewer before including it into latex? without a reproducible test file I think that will be impossible to debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes the image is fine. Plus I have used it before and ran and compiled the paper perfectly. Now I got back to the document after a few months and did some modification to the text as per reviewer comments. But I got shocked by this issue.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'll try changing the image to see if the issue persists

Comment: I just added an update to the question. It seems that the issue only happens for rectangular images. How do I solve this?

Comment: there is no way anyone can tell you how to solve that unless you can make a test available, it just doesn't happen, there must be something specific either to the png file or the way it is being included into tex.

Comment: That doesn't look white at all. Could  be a coloured box or something. No telling from this information, though.

Comment: Even after your edits there is no way to reproduce this issue.  I'm voting to close as unclear.