# White box and artifacts over the corner of a PNG image

Tags: png, includegraphics

I seem to have run into the same issue [as described in this (previously closed) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370088/56381).

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{loop.png}
    \caption{A 16-bit PNG image.}
\end{figure}
```

Here is the image being included:

[image: 16-bit PNG image]

Compilation succeeds without warning (`pdflatex`), but the resulting PDF shows artifacts and a white box in the corner of the image (when opened in Preview):

[image]

Comment: could be some sort of transparent layer over the image. I don't see, how this is related to *TeX in any way...

Comment: It is related to TeX because the PNG is fine when viewed in any software, and artifacts appear only after including it in a TeX document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artifacts disappear when converting the 16-bit PNG image into 8-bit PNG. This is easily done with Preview, ImageMagick or image editing software.

[image]

For context, my original 16-bit PNG was the result of using `convert` on an EXR image, and so it took me a while to realize that it was 16-bit.

Comment: probably you should flag this with pdftex maintainers to check if it is an undocumented limitation of the system, or a fault in that particular png or a bug in pdftex.